# How to disable Avast's virus database update popup notification?

Tags: anti-virus, notifications, avast

It annoys me, but I can't find in the settings how to disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

> Settings > Updates > Details and uncheck box that says
>
> "Show notification box after automatic update"

[image: Avast Settings page - Show notification box after automatic update]

Comment: I just unchecked all of them. Let's wait a week for the results

Comment: I have unchecked all of them in 2 computers. In one of the computers (the one I use) it has disappeared. In the other I saw the message recently.

Comment: Outdated as of July 2013.

Comment: @ruda.almeida updated with new screen shot, hope that helps.

Comment: Why didn't you remove the old version? Anyway, your updated answer is wrong. @Ian's is right.

Comment: Nice screenshot, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

Try Sounds -> Settings -> avast! antivirus branch -> click on 'automatic vps update' -> click on the 'sounds' drop down menu -> select 'none' -> apply.

mick.

Answer (score 1):

To kill sound: right click on avast icon -> Program Settings -> Sounds -> check the box "disable avast sounds".

Disable PopUp: **Program Settings** -> **Update (Basic)** -> now there's a button in the lower right corner called "**Details**", click on it -> uncheck "show sliding box after automatic update"

Answer (score 1):

click on icon of avast next click on stop memory test next click on database only next click on update(basic) next click on confirmations and uncheck the options "Message when results were successfully processed.Next click ok. Its done.

Answer (score 1):

I've found in the new version (7.0.*) you can go to Settings -> Updates -> Details and uncheck the box that says "Show notification box after automatic update."